# Has and belongs to many implementation Questions / Tags

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-design, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

Lets take Stackoverflow as an example:

Two models: Questions and Tags

A Question can have many Tags.

Should a separate table "Question_tags" be created to manage the associations or is there a way to create an array field in the Questions table.

Which is better? Would a dedicated "Question_tags" table be overkill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I **strongly recommend you to use a Tag model** instead of serialized attributes like Array of Hash:

A model is a lot more flexible. In the future you may want to add new features about the Tags, like a search function, custom-ordering, or notation. With a serialized attribute, it will be difficult to do this kind of stuff.

Imagine you want to find every question having the tag "*hello-world*", you would have to make a complex SQL query to retrieve all questions having this tag, instead of just a simple `Tag.where(name: 'hello-world').first.questions` to retrieve the related questions.

Also, you could make your Tag model polymorphic, which would allow you to assign tags to every objects you defined as "taggable".

---

To define the association in your models:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :question_tag_relations
  has_many :tags, through: question_tag_relations

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :question_tag_relations
  has_many :questions, through: question_tag_relations

class QuestionTagRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :tag
  validates :question_id, presence: true # optionnal
  validates :tag_id, presence: true # optionnal
```

You need to generate the corresponding migration in order to create the question_tag_relations table.

Comment: I have a "Tag" model already. My question is how to best store the associations of a "Question has many tags".

Comment: +1 for separate table, you should avoid data duplication has much as possible or it will become an update nightmare.